# How to upgrade the angular version from 7 to 11 and is it recommend to upgrade?

Tags: angular7

Im trying to upgrade the angular version from 7 to 11 and getting the unhandled exception occured error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H25O4.png)

Comment: This blog may be usefull http://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2021/05/upgrade-angular-version-to-latest.html

Answer (score 0):

If you already have done an upgrade of the Angular version from 7 to 11 and if everything works fine except the error as shown while running the following command

```
npm start
```

then you can modify your package.json file and add the following to the scripts section:

```
"postinstall": "ngcc"
```

Hope that it could be a workaround!